# Pack tuple with its index range

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

I'm wondering whether there is a way to pack tuple with its index range (possibly using [`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)). Basically, what I want to achieve is

```
template <typename... Us, std::size_t... Idx>
void func(??? arg_pack) {
  // std::get<Idx>(std::move(arg_pack.args))...
}
```

The following does not work, but demonstrates my intention.

```
template <typename... Us, std::size_t... Idx>
struct arg_pack {
  std::tuple<Us...> args;
  std::index_sequence<Idx...> idx;
};
```

**Update:**

[This](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/lock_free/blob/master/lf/arg_pack.hpp) is the solution I practically adopted with [sample usage](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/lock_free/commit/9b4a667ee805b87c92451b4e928d100e291744c1). Hope this throws more light on my intention.

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't want `template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... Idx> struct arg_pack { Tuple args; std::index_sequence<Idx...> idx; };` ? This style would support all tuple-likes, such as `std::pair` and `std::array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the usual problem of the double variadic list: you can have only one at the end of the variadic parameters.

I suggest to pack the index list in a type (the usual `std::index_sequence`) and put it in first place.

I mean, something like

```
template <typename...>
struct arg_pack;

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct arg_pack<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
 {
   static_assert( sizeof...(Is) == sizeof...(Ts) , "!" );

   std::tuple<Ts...>          args;
   std::index_sequence<Is...> idx;
 };
```

So the `func()` can be written as follows

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
void func (arg_pack<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...> && ap)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (std::get<Is>(std::move(ap.args)), 0)... };
 }
```

I also suggest the declaration (not definition, in the way of `std::declval()`... but you can also create a `make_arg_pack()` to create the object starting from a list of `Ts...` values) of a `declArgPack()` function

```
template <typename ... Ts>
arg_pack<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...> declArgPack ();
```

to simplify the creation of the type, and the definition of a template `using` type, to simplify the use of `declArgPack()`

```
template <typename ... Ts>
using arg_pack_type = decltype(declArgPack<Ts...>());
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...>
struct arg_pack;

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct arg_pack<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
 {
   static_assert( sizeof...(Is) == sizeof...(Ts) , "!" );

   std::tuple<Ts...>          args;
   std::index_sequence<Is...> idx;
 };

template <typename ... Ts>
arg_pack<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...> declArgPack ();

template <typename ... Ts>
using arg_pack_type = decltype(declArgPack<Ts...>());

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
void func (arg_pack<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...> && ap)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (std::get<Is>(std::move(ap.args)), 0)... };
 }

int main ()
 {
   arg_pack_type<short, int, long, long long>  ap0;

   func(std::move(ap0));
 }
```

Comment: I would define a macro for `arg_pack<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>`.

Comment: @Lingxi - A macro :( ? I've developed `declArgPack()` to simplify the definitions of `arg_pack`'s and avoid the use of macros. General suggestion: when possible, avoid c-style macros.

Comment: @Lingxi - Answer modified: introduced `arg_pack_type` to simplify the use of `declArgPack()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I aim to simplify the declaration of `func()`. The designed use case is to group arguments in variadic templates.

Comment: That is, you can pass multiple `arg_pack`s to `func()` like `func(pack_args(a, b, c), pack_args(d), pack_args(e, f))`.

Comment: The [solution](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/lock_free/blob/master/lf/arg_pack.hpp) I adopted with [usage](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/lock_free/blob/master/lf/stack.hpp#L51). Hope this throws some light on my intention.

Comment: @Lingxi - sorry, no: isn't clear to me what do you want to do. But I'm not sure that you need an `arg_pack` dedicated struct. Given a variadic list of `Ts...` types, what about using `std::tuple<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>` instead of `arg_pack`?

Comment: Then when unpacking, I need to ignore index 0 and start from 1, which I think needs another function template. Now, I can do the unpacking inline.

Comment: I think the original intention could be summarized as allowing passing multiple argument packs, each contain a varying number of arguments. For example, see [this](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/Happy_Hacking_CXX/blob/master/manual.md#pack_args).

Comment: @Lingxi - I understand a little more ... only a little; anyway, I don't think another function template is needed; your `node` constructor become `template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Us> node (std::tuple<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Us...> && t) : data{std::forward<Us>(std::get<1U+Is>(t))...}, next{}, cnt{} { }`